# Tensorflow gradient producing different output for same input

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to understand how tensorflow.gradient works. I tried to run the following piece of code:

```
a = tf.constant([2,2,2])
b = 2*a
c=tf.constant([4,4,4])
print(b)
print(c)
g = tf.gradients(c, a)
g1 = tf.gradients(b, a)



with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(g1))
    print(sess.run(g))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lo8zd.png)

Though b and c are same, g1 produces the correct result but g gives none. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0):

because the given tensors are unconnected. 
The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) has precisely an example about this (with a typo :-))

```
a = tf.ones([1, 2])
b = tf.ones([3, 1])
g1 = tf.gradients([b], [a], unnconnected_gradients='none')
sess.run(g1)  # [None]

g2 = tf.gradients([b], [a], unconnected_gradients='zero')
sess.run(g2)  # [array([[0., 0.]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I checked the definition of unconnected means is the value returned for each x in xs if it is unconnected in the graph to ys. But in my example, the input values are the same in both cases. If we print the values of b and c, values are the same. Can you please explain why particularly one case is giving none and the other is giving the correct result?

Comment: Because they are *not connected*. if you change in your example `a`, then `b` will change aswell, thats the whole point of "connected". `b` and `c` are **not** the same, just type `type(b/c)` and see the difference